# Python TicTacToe minimax choses wrong option

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm currently trying to implement an AI for my Python TicTacToe game.
Everything performs greatly, apart from one single situation.
My current code:

```
def testLine(line):
    '''
    ' :param line: Liste containing 3 ints
    ' :return:   1, if all elements of the list == 1
    '           -1, if all elements of the list == -1
    '            0, otherwise
    '''

    if line[0] == 1 and line[1] == 1 and line[2] == 1:
        return 1
    elif line[0] == -1 and line[1] == -1 and line[2] == -1:
        return -1
    return 0


def getWinner(board):
    # test columns
    for idx in range(3):
        line = [board[0][idx], board[1][idx], board[2][idx]]
        if not testLine(line) == 0:
            return line[0]

    # test rows
    for idx in range(3):
        line = board[idx]
        if not testLine(line) == 0:
            return line[0]

    # test diagonals
    line = [board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]]
    if not testLine(line) == 0:
        return line[0]
    line = [board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]]
    if not testLine(line) == 0:
        return line[0]

    # no winner
    return 0

def count(board, obj):
    c = 0
    for r in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[r])): # FIXED IT
            if board[r][col] == obj:
                c += 1
    return c

def nextMove(board, player):

    if len(board[0]) + len(board[1]) + len(board[2]) == 1: return 0, 4
    nextPlayer = player * (-1)

    if not getWinner(board) == 0:
        if player is 1: return -1, (-1, -1)
        else: return 1, (-1, -1)
    listOfResults = [] # empty array

    if count(board, 0) == 0: # there is no empty field
        return 0, (-1, -1)

    _list = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                _list.append((i, j))

    for (i, j) in _list:
        board[i][j] = player
        ret, move = nextMove(board, nextPlayer)
        listOfResults.append(ret)
        board[i][j] = 0
    if player is 1:
        maxPossibleValue = max(listOfResults)
        return maxPossibleValue, _list[listOfResults.index(maxPossibleValue)]
    else:
        minPossibleValue = min(listOfResults)
        return minPossibleValue, _list[listOfResults.index(minPossibleValue)]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str(nextMove([[ 1,  -1,  0],
                        [ -1, -1,  1],
                        [ 1,  1,  0]],
                       -1)))
```

Output: `(0, (0, 2))`

I can say for sure that `count`, `getWinner` and `testLine` work perfectly.
But the output of the scenario at the very bottom of the code is simply wrong, as *it should be `(0, 2, 2)`* because the computer has to "block" my chance to win in the bottom line.
Do you have suggestions on how to fix my minimax algorithm?

**EDIT: I've fixed it.** The error was in the `count` method. You shouldn't say

```
for col in board[r]
```

but

```
for col in range(len(board[r]))
```

Because otherwise it won't keep the elements in the right order and the whole method returned a false value.

Comment: 1) write unittests for each method
2) I assume, that problem may be related to lists (they are mutable, additionally if you modify linked copy of list (created by assignment), original list gets modified too)

Comment: @Ser I've just edited this question as I successfully fixed it. Thank you for the idea of the unittests, they helped me a lot. I originally thought that there'll never be an error in the `count` method, so I didn't really test it. You made me think about it, and I managed to get the function right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it. The error was in the count method. You shouldn't say

```
for col in board[r]
```

but

```
for col in range( len(board[r]) )
```

Because otherwise it won't keep the elements in the right order and the whole method returned a false value.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is that `return a, b` is similar to `return (a,b)`, because defining a tuple does not need parenthesis (exept for an empty tuple).

So you can easily return `(0, 0, 2)` instead of `(0, (0, 2))` :

```
return (maxPossibleValue,) + _list[listOfResults.index(maxPossibleValue)]
# use (a,) for a tuple of len 1
```

But I'm aware this solves only the half of your problem.

Comment: I know, but this "return format" helps me to access the different values easier.
"But I'm aware this solves only the half of your problem." It doesn't really fix the problem at all, but thank you anyways! :)

Comment: I was confused because you said "_it should be `(0, 2, 2)`_" :) I'm taking a look at the algorithm itself...

Comment: Damn that was stupid. The error was in the `count` method. It shouldn't be `for col in board[r]` but `for col in range(len(board[r]))`, as I don't keep it in the right order otherwise. Thanks for your help!